# Return only matches from substitution in Perl 5.8.8 (was: Perl "p" regex modifier equivalent)

Tags: regex, perl, perl5.8

I've got a script ([source](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/scripts/__svn_ps1.sh)) to parse `svn info` to create a suitable string for Bash's `$PS1`. Unfortunately this doesn't work on one system I'm using which is running Perl 5.8.8 - It outputs all lines instead of only the matches. What would be the Perl 5.8.8 equivalent to the following?

```
__svn_ps1()
{
    local result=$(
        svn info 2>/dev/null | \
        perl -pe 's;^URL: .*?/((trunk)|(branches|tags)/([^/]*)).*;\2\4 ;p')
    if [ -n "$result" ]
    then
        printf "${1:- (%s)}" $result
    fi  
}
```

The output from Perl 5.10 contains only a space, parenthesis, one of branch name, tag name or `trunk`, and the end parenthesis. The output from Perl 5.8.8 (without the final `p`) contains this *plus* a parenthesized version of each space-separated part of the `svn info` output.

A possible workaround involves a simple `grep '^URL: '` between the `svn` and `perl` commands, but I was hoping to avoid that since this will be executed for each Bash prompt.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do - give an input file and what outputyou expect.

Comment: Maybe I sound like a stuck record but "Can you explain what you are trying to do - give an input file and what outputyou expect".  You are presenting a lot of half baked solutions but I can't work out what you want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you only want output from a line that matches, don't use the `-p` command-line switch. It prints the value of `$_` at the end of each loop. You might want something with the `-n` command-line switch:

```
 perl -ne 'print if s/.../.../'
```

I'd do it in the same way for Perl v5.8 and v5.10. I'm not sure what you think the `/p` modifier is doing since you don't use the `` $` ``, `$&`, or `$'` variables or their per-match equivalents.

You can read about the command-line switches in [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html).

Comment: Thanks, that was just the thing! I had misunderstood `/p` and what it did. Still weird that Perl 5.10 doesn't print all the lines, though.

Answer (score 6):

As of perl 5.10, the `/p` switch tells perl to put matched content into `${^PREMATCH}`, `${^MATCH}` and `${^POSTMATCH}`.

And the one-liner you've posted never uses those vars, so omit the `/p`.

UPDATE: Trying to keep up with the initial question...

```
perl -ne 's/search/replace/ and print'
```

Will only print lines for which the replacement was made. Note `-n` versus `-p` switch. Also, I've tried the `-p` `/p` combo on my 5.10 and it happily prints unaltered non-matching lines too. Maybe I missed something...

Comment: Clarified the question - The issue is more on what's returned from Perl.